# Sharepoint Create Incremental Unique ID with Concatenation

Tags: microsoft-flow

I am a newbie in power automate.

I have managed to have the flow working from collecting data from Microsoft Forms to create an item in Sharepoint List.

Now, I have these 2 columns

Requisition ID: [Abbreviation]_YYMMDD_xxxx

Abbreviation: The value could be ABC or DEF based on a mapping that I had done

Now, I have problem creating the incremental unique ID

If the sharepoint list has nothing on ABC for 26 September, then

a Requisition ID should be ABC/220926/0001 should be created

If the sharepoint list already have ABC/220926/0001 and ABC/220926/0002,

then it should create ABC/220926/0003

Same goes for DEF and other abbreviation.

Any idea on how to do the incremental based on the condition stated above.
Would appreciate your screenshot guidance on this.

I have tried for 2 weeks on this by a lot of trial and error.
But I am not getting it right at all.

I do not have programming background, would appreciate your help on this.

Answer (score 0):

Apologies in advance for the long and convoluted answer. Hopefully someone else has an easier way of solving this for you, but my solution appears to meet your requirements. As you're new to Power Automate, I've added some clarifying notes to explain some things that I think might cause you some errors.

**Assumptions:**

1. The date in the RequisitionID is the Created date of the list item
2. `Abbreviation` is the internal name of the field and it is a Choice field
3. `RequisitionID` is the internal name of the field and it is a single line of text field

If any of these assumptions are incorrect, my solution would need to be adjusted accordingly

**Solution**

1. When an Item is Created

   - Nothing special about this trigger. Just set the Site and List.
     [image]
2. Get Item

   - Nothing special about this action. Set the Site and List and use the ID from Step 1.
   - This action gets all the metadata of the new list item.
     [image]
3. Get Items.

   - Show advanced options
   - Set Filter Query to
     `startswith(RequisitionID,'@{concat(outputs('Get_item')?['body/Abbreviation/Value'],'/',formatDateTime(outputs('Get_item')?['body/Created'],'yyMMdd'))}')`
   - This formula filters all the items in the list that have a requisitionID that have the same Abbreviation and created date. (eg all items where the requisitionID begins with ABC/220928)
   - Set `Order By` to `RequisitionID desc`
   - This will sort them by Requisition ID, newest first.
   - Set `Top Count` to `1`
   - This will ensure that only the last result is returned
     [image]
4. Initialize variable

   - Name: `varNewRequisitionIdIncrement`  Type: `Integer` Value: `{blank}`
     [image]
5. Condition

   - `length(outputs('Get_Latest_RequistionID_with_the_same_Abbreviation_and_date')?['body/value'])` is equal to `1`
   - This checks if Step 3 returned any results. There will either be 0 or 1  results returned.
   - The formula is based on the name of the Step 3 Action `(Get_Latest_RequistionID_with_the_same_Abbreviation_and_date)`. You would need to adjust the formula to reflect this, or ensure your Step 3 Action has the exact same name as mine.
6. If `Yes`

   i. Get Item

   - ID: `first(outputs('Get_Latest_RequistionID_with_the_same_Abbreviation_and_date')?['body/value'])?['ID']`
   - As with the step above, this formula is based on the name of the Step 3 Action.

   ii. Set Variable

   - Name: `varNewRequisitionIdIncrement` (initialized in Step 4)
   - Value: `add(int(substring(outputs('Get_details_of_the_returned_result')?['body/RequisitionID'],add(lastIndexOf(outputs('Get_details_of_the_returned_result')?['body/RequisitionID'],'/'),1))),1)`
   - This formula is based on the name of Step `6i`
   - In plain English, it gets all the characters after the last `/`, converts it from a string to an integer and adds 1 to the result.
7. If `No`

   i. Set Variable

   - Name: `varNewRequisitionIdIncrement` (initialized in Step 4)
   - Value: `1`
   - If no items are returned from Step 3, Set the increment to 1

[image]

8. Initialize Variable

   - Name: `varNewRequisitionID`
   - Type: `String`
   - Value: `concat(outputs('Get_item')?['body/Abbreviation/Value'],'/',formatDateTime(outputs('Get_item')?['body/Created'],'yyMMdd'),'/',formatNumber(variables('varNewRequisitionIdIncrement'),'D4'))`
   - Plain English: Combine  the `Abbreviation` value, a forward slash `/`, the date created in `yyMMdd` format, another forward slash `/` and the `varNewRequisitionIdIncrement` in a 4 digit format
     [image]
9. Set Item

   - Set the `RequisitionID` field to `varNewRequisitionID`
     [image]